# Checking if a typed object array is not empty

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a Item[] _items array of items, where some of the items may be null. I wish to check if the array contains at least one non-null item.

My current implementations seems a little complicated:

```
    internal bool IsEmtpy { get { return (!(this.NotEmpty)); } }
    private bool IsNotEmpty { get { return ( this.Items.Any(t => t != null));} }
```

So my question is: **Is there a simpler way to check if a typed array of reference objects contains at least one non null object?**

Comment: Why do you think this is complicated?

Comment: Why do you think it's complicated? it seems quite clear and compact to my eyes. Maybe you can put this logic to a custom extension mehod, but the logic itself won't change.

Comment: Don't agree with the downvote, it's a clear question.

Comment: @leppie (and Steve B) I hate the double negation. In my implementation it's empty if it's not not empty :(

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks. Downvotes are so unhelpful, and are the reason why I quit "programmers"...

Comment: @Avi Well, generally I disagree - downvotes on questions filter out the poor questions quickly, however, downvotes on perfectly good questions are unhelpful.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth At the end of most poor questions are poor users wanting answers. Why filter them out?

Comment: @Avi They are "poor" because they are hard to understand or show that the user isn't putting much effort into the problem. If there is a genuine problem, then the user can spend time to create a well thought-out question to help the community help them. Of course, I don't think any of this applies to your question, but unfortunately there is no way to moderate downvotes other than with upvotes, hence I up-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no complexity in your implementation. Basically, the only way to check whether there are non-null values in the array is to look through all values until you will reach non-null value or the end of the array.

The following code is easier to understand though:

```
internal bool IsEmtpy { get { return this.Items.All(t => t == null); } }
private bool IsNotEmpty { get { return this.Items.Any(t => t != null); } }
```

And it is probably better to extend `IEnumerable` as follows:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static bool ContainsOnlyEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        return source.All(t => t == null);
    }

    public static bool ContainsNonEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        return source.Any(t => t != null);
    }

}
```

and use it like this: `bool nonEmpty = this.Items.ContainsNonEmpty();`

Comment: @leppie Please, forgive me my terrible English :)

Comment: No problem, I had to look up the meaning too ;p

Comment: @leppie I didn't remember the word exactly, so I even opened the dictionary to look up for it... but then I completely forgot about it and submitted the answer :)

Comment: Thanks - It's the "all" I've been missing, though now that I understand the answer I think the double negation is more efficient because most of my arrays are "mostly full" so the any-not-null will return faster.

Comment: @Avi - no, there's no performance difference. Both `Any` and `All` return as soon as a non-null element is found.

Comment: Doesn't this code require a constraint that ensure TSource is a class ?

Comment: @SteveB No, but the methods need to be `static`. All you will get without the constraint is a value type can never be null.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I can't believe I omitted the `static` keyword. That's inadmissibly many mistakes in a single answer.

Comment: @penartur No problem, easily done when using brain-compilers in an answer. I chose to edit and correct as opposed to downvote.